# Getting the _id of the record in autoform on a method-update in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using the [autoform package](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#callbackshooks) for meteor, but when I try to update a document in a collection, I can't seem to get the `_id` of the record to update it.

I am using autoform with `type=method-update` so I can validate it server side.  When I try the code below it fails because `_id` is undefined.

template:

```
{{#autoForm collection="Lessons" doc=lesson id="updateLessonForm"  type="method-update" meteormethod="updateLesson"}}
        <fieldset>
            {{> afFieldInput name="categoryId" firstOption="(Select a Category)" options=categoryOptions}}
            {{> afQuickField name='title'}}
            {{> afQuickField name='summary' rows=2}}
            {{> afQuickField name='detail' rows=1}}
            {{> afQuickField name='extras' rows=1}}
            {{> afQuickField name='active'}}
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Update Lesson</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
```

server side method:

```
updateLesson: function (doc) {
    check(doc, Lessons.simpleSchema());
    Lessons.update({_id: this._id}, doc);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
doc._id returns undefined

doc returns:
I20150409-23:15:22.671(-5)? { '$set': 
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?    { categoryId: 1,
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      title: 'Lesson 1 update',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      summary: 'Summary for lesson 2',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      detail: '<p>dsffdsfd</p>',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      extras: '<p>fdsf</p>',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      active: false } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you print doc, you should get the document, so `this._id` should be changed to `doc._id`.

**NOTE:** try using `console.log` to see the values you are getting,before do the update.

```
console.log(this._id)//should return undefined.
console.log(doc._id)//should return the id
console.log(doc)//should return the doc.
```

**Update**

In order to get the `_id`, you should call a second parameter.

```
updateLesson: function (doc,doc_id) {
    check(doc, Lessons.simpleSchema());
    Lessons.update({_id: this._id}, doc);
}
```

Comment: doc._id returns undefined

Comment: I20150409-23:15:22.671(-5)? { '$set': 
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?    { categoryId: 1,
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      title: 'Lesson 1 update',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      summary: 'Summary for lesson 2',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      detail: '<p>dsffdsfd</p>',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      extras: '<p>fdsf</p>',
I20150409-23:15:22.672(-5)?      active: false } }

Comment: and `console.log(doc)` what returns? also i totally forgot you should do the update like this `Lessons.update({_id: doc._id}, {$set:{field:doc.newValue}});` did you try with the hook? and the `onSuccess` callback?

Comment: I edited the question to show the logs from a doc. I am using the method-update https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#method-update  I don't believe I need to do a callback hook when utilizing the method type.  Maybe my understanding is wrong.  With method update it says it passes two arguments and one is the documentId.  I can not figure out how the documentId is suppose to be accessed in the server side method though.

Comment: got it, it say the method should have 2 parameters, so the method should look like this `updateLesson: function (doc,doc_id) {
   console.log(doc)
  console.log(doc._id)
    check(doc, Lessons.simpleSchema());
    Lessons.update({_id: this._id}, doc);
}` use 2 parameters on the method, `doc,docID`

Comment: doc._id returned undefined to me. What worked was using ``documentId``